# Authorization Issue while integrating the Payum module in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, authorization, payum

I have successfully integrated the payum module with my zf2 project, But now when the module goes to capture the payment zend gives an error as:

```
 Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Resource PayumCapture not defined' in \vendor\coolcsn\csn-authorization\src\CsnAuthorization\Module.php:
```

While I have add the controller methods in my **acl.global** as follows:

```
 'Reisesparer\Controller\Payment' => array(
      'paypalEc' => 'guest',
      'stripeJs' => 'guest',
      'done' => 'guest',
      'PayumCapture' => 'guest'
  ),
```

But still the above error is showing how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What are you using for authorization? (A third party module or your own implementation?)

Comment: I am using **CsnAuthorization** module for authorization @Dymen

Comment: when i disable this module it works fine but i need this one too because i am using it for different purposes. @Dymen1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your authorization isn't looking for the resource via your controller. Could you try adding:
`'PayumCapture' => array('all' => 'guest',),`

To your acl.config

Comment: Where exactly i will put this piece of code? after the resources? like this
'resources' => array(
            'allow' => array(
                 'PayumCapture' => array('all' => 'guest',),
)
),

Comment: Put it in your Acl.global

Comment: Yeah I did it will help others too find out the best solution.@Dymen1

Comment: Can you please have a look on this one too? now getting this error:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085211/ssl-certificate-isssue-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate @Dymen1